# Rapsberry Pi Camera v3 issues

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspicam, picamera, libcamera

I want to make a Rpi4 8GB livestream 2 camera feeds over 4G (SIM7600X module). One camera is a generic action cam and the other one is a PiCamera v3, which I have issues with. I'm running Raspbian Bullseye, and followed the official documentation for its' setup.

For whatever reason, the `libcamera-hello` command works just fine with the PiCam, but when using `vcgencmd get_camera` I'm getting `supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0`. Also, when using guvcview, it doesn't seem to appear in the device list, the device list is as follows:

```
 - rpivid
 - bcm2835-codec-decode
 - bcm2835-codec-encode
 - bcm2835-codec-isp
 - bcm2835-codec-image_fx
 - bcm2835-codec-encode_image
 - bcm2835-isp (this one appears 8 times in total)
 - unicam (appears 2 times in total)
```

Inside VLC I can use the following capture devices:

```
 - /dev/video0
 - /dev/video1
 - /dev/video10 - 16
 - /dev/video18 - 23
 - /dev/video31
```

When trying to use any of them other than video0 I'm getting an `Input can't be opened` error

So far I've done:

1. Rewinding to Buster 32-bit
2. Updating Rpi4 firmware
3. Downloading libcamera-apps again
4. Made sure camera support is enabled in `raspi-config`
5. Made sure my `/boot/config.txt` file has `camera_auto_detect=1`

I've been trying to make it work for 3 days now and I'm completely lost, it's supposed to be an easy task to get it up and running properly but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help or input is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: get_camera only works with the old legacy stack https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=325563#p1948351